# my problem is in omitting the auxiliaries i want to know when do we omit an auxiliary verb

Tags: grammar

I saw a movie in the movie there was a question : how was he like and the answer was he's so nice and there was another question: how she like the the answer was:pretty. well i want to know if i didn't hear the auxiliary or it is omitted in the second question 
.
Sara:how was he like? 
Lele:he's so nice

Then

Jonh:how she like 
Alex:pretty

Comment: You cannot write a NEW identical question, it's only going to get closed again by a mod. EDIT the first one, include the dialogue in that one. It's nearly done. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261795/object-question-subject-question-differences

Comment: I wrote the dialogue

Comment: I am sorry, it still makes zero sense. Especially the part you are specifically asking about. "How she like" is simply not an English sentence.

Comment: @kimia please go back to your previous question and edit it. do not post another question.

Comment: That is exactly my problem

Comment: No, that is not your problem. You do not have a problem. The movie has. You do not. Let the movie be an idiot if it wants to.

Comment: Ok give me your insta id so i can tag you under the post

Comment: Please stop posting this question. Please, please, please.

Comment: @JakeRegier It's OK, It's OK, OK? Just relax. The original question has now been reopened. If you answer it well enough, I'll upvote you, promise.